# Set the same value for multiple identifiers in a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, object

i have an object that stores a table for converting a json response in a user readeable text. The thing is, the same text applies for multiple json conditions.
I want to know if there's a way to set the same value for 2 different Id's in a object.
Like, instead of:

```
var msg = {
    "error_code1": "user_msg",
    "error_code2": "user_msg",
}
```

Something like this

```
var msg = {
    "error_code1" && "error_code2": "user_msg",
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: "no" - which is unfortunately too short an answer to be an answer so I'm leaving it as a comment

Comment: You can of course use a variable instead of a string. Which would allow you to change the message in only one place if you need to change it.

Comment: what is the goal, to avoid typing the same `“user_msg”` for different error codes?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yeap, thats it.

Comment: Your curly quotes are unlikely to work very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First approach** is using "getter" functions to reference the initial object:

```
var errorBindings = {
    'errorCode101': 'Unauthorized request',
    get 'errorCode102'() { return this.errorCode101; },
    get 'errorCode103'() { return this.errorCode101; },
    'errorCode104': 'All fields are required',
    get 'errorCode105'() { return this.errorCode104; },
};

console.log(errorBindings.errorCode103);  // "Unauthorized request"
```

**Second approach** is using an anonymous function with referencing properties from which we should borrow the needed value:

```
var messages = function(o) {
    o.errorCode101 = 'Authorization error!';
    o.errorCode102 = o.errorCode101;
    o.errorCode103 = o.errorCode101;
    o.errorCode104 = 'All fields are required';
    return o;
}({});

console.log(messages.errorCode101);  // "Authorization error!"
console.log(messages.errorCode103);  // "Authorization error!"
```

Comment: Nice, just what i needed. Thx

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var msg = {};
msg['a'] = msg['b'] = 'value';
```

But for such simple cases I prefer to repeat myself instead of doing premature optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in JSON all keys must be strings so what you are attempting will not work.

As a work around I can suggest storing a reference to the value of the user_msg and assigning it to each error code key.

For example:

```
var storedMessage = "user_msg";

var msg = {
  "error_code1": storedMessage,
  "error_code2": storedMessage
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.